# Adding NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers doesn't work

Tags: password, sudo, root

On 14.04 here. I SSHed into my machine, added the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
myuser   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And then tried running:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/blah
```

...**and I'm being asked for my password. Why?!?**

I do *not* want to be asked for my password when doing this operation.  Please note that when I run `ls -ltr /` I get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 94 root root  4096 Jul 30 13:28 etc
```

But I don't think this matters because I've set myself up as a "sudoer", right?

More importantly, what do I need to do so that I can run `sudo mkdir /etc/blah` as my current user (`myuser`) without being asked for the password?

Here's my entire `/etc/sudoers` file:

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root      ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
fizzbuzz  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
chadmin   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Could you post your sudoers file? The directive is right, but it could not work due to the context.

Comment: Thanks @Letizia - please see my update, anything jump out at you?

Comment: I guess I should also note that I did *not* use `visudo` however any manual edits to this file were not copy-n-paste jobs, I typed everything in as-is. **But does `visudo` edit other files besides this one?** That might be it...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is sudoers NOPASSWD option not working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working)

Comment: Also, check any files in `/etc/sudoers.d/`, they may be overriding things from `/etc/sudoers`

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It is the sequence/ordering of the rules that caused this. The last rule takes preference.

In order to fix your problem, simply move your lines,

```
fizzbuzz  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
chadmin   ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

from the **`sudoers`** file to

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/myOverrides
```

This is better approach than editing the `sudoers` file with a plain text editor. If you accidentally insert errors into the file, you may not longer be able to run **`sudo`**. Always use **`visudo`**, so that the syntax is checked and you receive warnings about mistakes!

Your directive doesn't work because it is overridden by:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

If you run the `groups` command you should see that your user belongs to these groups.

Comment: The file's name should follow a convention of `nn-somename`, for example `/etc/sudoers.d/20-myoverrides`

Comment: Yes, of course, if you have more than one file, these are parsed in sorted lexical order, so it is a good practice to use a number and it will be easy to know that order.

Answer (score 26):

If **myuser** is in the **sudo** group, then this order of the lines won't provide passwordless access (as noted by Florian Diesch), because the 3rd line overrides the 1st one.

```
myuser    ALL=(www-data:www-data) NOPASSWD: ALL
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

So just put the lines into this order:

```
# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
myuser    ALL=(www-data:www-data) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Under **myuser** account use `sudo -l` to check what permissions **myuser** has.

Answer (score 12):

If multiple entries match for a user the *last* one is used. So if `fizzbuzz` and `chadmin` are members of the groups `admin` or `sudo` they will be still asked for a password.

Put the two lines at the end of the `sudoers` file after the `#includedir` line.

Comment: Indeed, so a combination of @Letizia's and your answers is the best, since the `#includedir` is the last entry in `sudoers` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally if you are customizing what commands can be run via `sudo` you should be making these changes in a separate file under `/etc/sudoers.d/` instead of editing the `sudoers` file directly. You should also always use `visudo` to edit the file(s). You should NEVER grant `NOPASSWD` on `ALL` commands.

Example:
`sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers.d/mynotriskycommand`

Insert your line granting permission:
`myuser ALL= NOPASSWD: /bin/mkdir`

Then save and exit and `visudo` will warn you if you have any syntax errors.

You can run `sudo -l` to see the permissions that your user has been granted, if any of the user specific `NOPASSWD` commands appear BEFORE any `%groupyouarein ALL=(ALL) ALL` command in the output you will be prompted for your password.

If you find yourself creating lots of these sudoers.d files then perhaps you will want to create them named per user so they are easier to visualize. Keep in mind that the ordering of the FILE NAMES and of the RULES within the file is very important, the LAST one loaded wins, whether it is MORE or LESS permissive than the previous entries.

> You can control the file name ordering by using a prefix of 00-99 or aa/bb/cc, though also keep in mind that if you have ANY files that don't have numeric prefix, they will load after the numbered files, overriding the settings. This is because depending on your language settings the "lexical sorting" the shell uses sorts numbers first and then may interleave upper and lowercase when sorting in "ascending" order.

Try running `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | sort` and `printf '%s\n' {{0..99},{A-Z},{a-z}} | LANG=C sort` to see whether your current language prints `AaBbCc` etc or `ABC` then `abc` to determine what the best "last" letter prefix to use would be.