# using a sudo command without a password for a certain app

Tags: scripts, sudo

I'm using a python script to run docker, but docker requires sudo commands to run and it's bad practice to store the sudo password in the file or give the whole python script sudo rights, I've seen a method where you enable the system to run certain commands without entering a password, I've tried it but 
I can't get my head around it, I mainly entered it wrongly (I think) I even corrupted my sudoers file once and fixed it.

So can anyone explain this line for me and why it's not working?

```
username ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker
```

Comment: Remove the spaces around `=` i.e. use `username ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/docker`

Comment: @heemayl still no use :(

Comment: Check the link on the updated answer..that could be a possible reason..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run an application using sudo without a password?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/39281/how-to-run-an-application-using-sudo-without-a-password)

Comment: @JacobVlijm i wanted an explanation for that line, not just how to use it and the manual just got me more confused :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent corrupting the `/etc/sudoers` file, always use the `visudo` command. If you don't like the default editor set the `EDITOR` environment variable to your desired one.

Put your *user specification* line as the last line in the `sudoers` file.

**Update**:

Please see: [Adding NOPASSWD in /etc/sudoers doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/a/504665/210170)

Comment: OP said `can anyone explain this line for me and why it's not working?` ..please add some explanation..

Comment: yes exactly what @heemayl said, i've found methods to restore it but i'm don't wanna do the trial and failure method with OS files, also didn't work

Comment: What does `sudo -l` say as run by your non-root user?

Comment: If your line is before the `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` line it will ask for a password. Updated my answer with a link to a better reply.

Answer (score 3):

Run the command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Now go to the entry of %sudo

```
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

and replace it with:

```
 %sudo   ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/docker
```

this will affect all sudo users. If you just want to do that option for one specific user"must have sudo permissions":

```
user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/docker
```

Now save and exit.

To be sure that everything is correct run the command:

```
sudo docker
```

It should run without prompting for user password.

**Hint:** Be sure your user has sudo permissions and be sure the path of the command is correct. you can check using `which docker`

Comment: Why are you suggesting that they remove the ability of all sudoers to run other commands with a password?

Comment: How did you see I suggest that?!

Comment: @Olathe I think you have to reread some concepts  http://askubuntu.com/questions/118204/sudoers-simple-explanation-requested

Comment: @Olathe And Why you are downvoting?!

Comment: You said to *replace* the line `%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` with another line. This means that you are deleting that line when you replace it with another line. Since the line you are deleting is the line that allows all sudoers to run other commands with a password, those sudoers won't be able to run other commands with a password.

Comment: Nope you misunderstand the syntax this just allow to run those sudoers the command docker without password and everything else remains as default. Read the answer in the uplink

Comment: Hint is the thing! :)