# Edit the /etc/sudoers file to provide permission to Jenkins

Tags: permissions, sudo, gedit, jenkins

I need to edit the `/etc/sudoers` file using the command:

```
 sudo gedit /etc/sudoers
```

and add the below:

```
jenkins ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Post adding and trying to save I am getting the error:

```
 (gedit:23062): WARNING **: 00:45:53.924: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported
```

Can somebody help?

Thanks
Sanjay

Comment: IMHO you should use visudo to edit the sudoers file as it checks syntax . See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-edit-the-sudoers-file-on-ubuntu-and-centos for a detailed discussion

Comment: Read `man sudoedit`, and you can use any editor you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `gedit`, `nautilus` and many other applications from the command line you will see these fake error messages often.

To confirm your changes took effect use the command:

```
sudo cat /etc/sudoers
```

You will see `gedit` did save the changes.

Comment: Thanks. It does save the changes but still receive the error in Jenkins while writing HelloWorld: HelloWorld.class (Permission denied)

Comment: Please read this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working