# cpupower frequency-set asks for permission despite being added to /etc/sudoers

Tags: sudo, cpupower

Recently cpupower stopped working when calling it *without* sudo.

I have the following line in `/etc/sudoers/`.

```
dimfred dimfred-schlap= NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/cpupower frequency-set *
```

Is this correct? AFAIK `*` should normally replace the following paramaters.

My usecase would be to call this line from a script with attached parameters. E.g. `sudo cpupower frequency-set --min 0.8Ghz --max 0.8Ghz`

When I run the command I get still prompted for the password.

The weird thing is that everything worked and suddenly broke. I don't know what happened there.

Running on:
`Ubuntu 20.04`
`Kernel 5.4.0-48-generic`

Fell free to ask for any other information you need. Thanks.

EDIT:

So I came around with writing subscripts. Those call a kind of "profile" (parameters for cpupower), the scripts itself are called without parameters. They work properly. Still would be interested why the above does not work cause I am not very pleased with having `n` extra scripts for each profile I have.

EDIT2:
So the answer was: order matters. I had first my command then the include.
Found it in this answer:
[Why is sudoers NOPASSWD option not working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Your `sudoers` file entry does NOT give you `root` all the time, just when you invoke `root`ness by prefacing your command with `sudo`, e.g.

```
sudo cpupower ...
```

Comment: I am sry. I also tried calling it with `sudo` then it still asks me for the password. I edit the question.

Comment: Btw I finally found the answer... it is so simple. The order matters. I first had my command in sudoers then the include. The other way round it works...
https://askubuntu.com/questions/100051/why-is-sudoers-nopasswd-option-not-working